# Creating Complex Android XML Component

Tags: android, xml, layout, components

I'm trying to make the following xml list:

[original list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYcMJ.png)

By the time, I've got this:

[my component (which will go inside a list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CpXM.png)

Here is my XML component code:

**list_item_issue.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/circle_line_shape"
    android:tint="@color/colorGray" />

<com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    app:bl_arrowDirection="left"
    app:bl_arrowHeight="14dp"
    app:bl_arrowPosition="10dp"
    app:bl_arrowWidth="8dp"
    app:bl_cornersRadius="0dp"
    app:bl_strokeWidth="0.5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parent_list_issue_title_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:text="Titulo de la incidencia"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parent_list_issue_subtitle_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/parent_list_issue_title_text_view"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_semi_transparent"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="Subtitulo de la incidencia - Texto de prueba aplicación" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/parent_list_item_expand_arrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_drop_down_circle"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout>
```

Here is my **circle_line_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
               android:gravity="center" />
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Problem is that I have no idea of how to make those circles + vertical lines aligned with the BubbleLayout like you can see on the original list image.

¿Shall I change my layout structure?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout, not a Linear.  Make the image view match_parent height.  Make the bubble layout_toEndOf the image view.  Make the relative_layout itself wrap_content.  This will make the relative layout the hight of the bubble layout, and the image the height of the relative layout.

Comment: doesn't work : ( ImageView height is now the entire screen and the other elements keep the same